# Linux server backup - MySQL and NFS share

Tags: backup

We currently use a cloud backup provider for MySQL and image files with a total source data volume of approx 22GB (growing with approx. 1 GB/month) - it works quite well but it is costing us around $150 a month including storage and it is getting both costly and also increasingly difficult to manage.

We are looking around for commercial software to help us do this but are struggling - we don't have the budget to pay for the Tier 1 products like Symantec, Commvault, EMC etc. We spent a lot of time trying R1Soft but (a) found it really weak at backing up MySQL and (b) it can't backup NFS shares.

We are looking at using mysqldump and rsync but the management will be messy and we would prefer something commercial, tested and supported.

Must have requirements are:

```
Linux (Centos)
Supports online MySQL backups
Support backup of NFS share
Encryption
Scheduling - we need to take multiple backups per day
Store x backups on remote server for x days
GUI interface
```

Nice to haves:

```
Ability to choose which tables to backup or whole database
Only backup changes - deduplication and/or compression would be great
Store x backups locally for x days (for quick restore)
Reporting / monitoring / email alerting
```

Budget is around $750 - $1000 for two servers to be protected - is there anything out there which can do this within the price point?